# Possible to setup "tab completion" for parameters in a custom PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I did a bit of looking around but haven't seen a way to do this.  Could I implement this through my script or would it have to be done somewhere else?

I would need users to be able to tab through the potential values for a parameter, not the parameter itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by [extending the TabExpansion function](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/the-new-tabexpansion-feature/).

Answer (score 5):

The [ValidateSet attribute](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743) can do this for a specific list of values.

eg.

```
function Compile (
    [ValidateSet("Debug", "Release")]
    [string]$config = "Debug"
)
{

}
```